# my loop skip empty data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a loop problem.
I want to collect name counts for each items for every months
This code skips variables with empty value, but I needs those values.
below is a bit of the tables involve

```
Name
  id int
  date date
  item_id int
```

so I need to loop them and put it in an array.

```
@names = Name.find(:all)
@list=Array.new
@names.each do |e|
 @list << Name.count(:all,:conditions=>["item_id = ? and DATE FORMAT(date,%M) = ?",e.item_id,date],:group =>DATE FORMAT(date,%m),:order=>"date ASC")
end
```

so, for every item_id which have empty count, it did not go into the array.
how do I include them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@list << Name.count(
  :all,
  :conditions=>["item_id = ? and DATE FORMAT(date,%M) = ?",e.item_id,date],
  :group =>DATE FORMAT(date,%m),
  :order=>"date ASC"
) || nil
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the blank/nil ids by selecting the IDs, OR `nil` IDs.

```
:conditions => ["(item_id = ? OR item_id = ?) and DATE FORMAT(date,%M) = ?", e.item_id, nil, date]
```

Comment: the nil/empty is the result count.not referring to item_id. let say i have names for item_id = 1,2 and 3. and there is no names for item_id = 2. so in the @list there will be only 2 results like [["01",2],["08",3]].i wish i have a way to put the item_id description as well in the array to make things more clearer.